# What is the semantics of '%' in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Googling doesn't help much in understand how the `%` variable is being used in the Makefile snippet below.

```
_OBJ = a.o b.o c.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(INC)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Can anybody please help me out? Does it mean that if there are five `.c` files present under `$(SRCDIR)`, that many `*.o` rules are being populated behind the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an "[implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html)".  The `%` makes the word `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` a *pattern*.  It tells make that if it's trying to build a target and the name of the target matches that pattern (where the `%` can substitute for one or more characters--any characters), AND that a file that matches the pattern `$(SRCDIR)/%.c` (where the `%` here has the same value as in the target) either already exists or can be built, then make can use this recipe to build that target.

So, if make wants to build a file `foo/bar.o` and the variable `OBJDIR` has the value `foo`, then this pattern `foo/%.o` will match that file with the `%` matching `bar` (this is called the *stem* in the GNU make documentation).

Then if `SRCDIR` has the value `blah` and make can find (or create) a file named `blah/bar.c`, then this implicit rule can be used to build the target `foo/bar.o` by running this recipe (`$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)`).

Comment: Perfect, makes complete sense coupled with the example.